# Continuous map from $SO(3)$ to angles

Tags: rotations, quaternions

At work we are presenting a 3D model on a web page using [three.js](https://threejs.org/). We also show the [Euler (Tait–Bryan) rotation angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) for the camera. One problem is that these angles sometimes behave in a strange way; suddenly two of the angles can change sign and the third start run in the opposite direction (e.g. decrease instead of increase).

**My question**:
Is there any formula giving a continuous map from $SO(3)$ to the angles? More precisely, if $R(\hat z, \gamma) R(\hat y, \beta) R(\hat x, \alpha) \in SO(3)$ how should $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be modified (in a continuous way) when another small rotation $R(n, \theta)$ is applied? Here $R(n, \theta)$ denotes a rotation angle $\theta$ around an axis with direction $n \in S^2$ and $\hat x, \hat y, \hat z$ are the unit vectors in the $x, y, z$ directions.

**What I have tried myself**:
Using [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) I have asserted 
$$
e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon c) \mathbf k}
e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon b) \mathbf j}
e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon a) \mathbf i}
=
e^{\frac12 \epsilon \theta \mathbf n}
e^{\frac12 \gamma \mathbf k}
e^{\frac12 \beta  \mathbf j}
e^{\frac12 \alpha \mathbf i}
$$
and expanded to first order in $\epsilon$. That worked quite fine, but I got a division by $\cos\beta$ resulting in a problem when $\cos\beta=0.$

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this is known as [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). There is no continuous mapping from $SO(3)$ to $(S^1)^3$ that would be an inverse to the Euler angle mapping going the other way. There are topological reasons why such a mapping cannot exist (look at the first homotopy).

Comment: When the $\cos\beta=0$ problem arose, I actually wondered if that was the gimbal lock. Now I see that the Wikipedia page about gimbal lock actually mentions this case: "An example worth examining happens when $\beta = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$."

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any formula giving a continuous map from $SO(3)$ to the angles?

Unfortunately no. There's no nonsingular three parameter chart on $SO(3)$.

> More precisely, if $R(\hat z, \gamma) R(\hat y, \beta) R(\hat x, \alpha) \in SO(3)$ how should $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be modified (in a continuous way) when another small rotation $R(n, \theta)$ is applied?

The best way to do this is to use a quaternion representation of the attitude and work out how a "small" norm rotational quaternion modifies the rotation. There's some work on that in the attitude determination literature. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09971).

> Using quaternions I have asserted 
>   $$
> e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon c) \mathbf k}
> e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon b) \mathbf j}
> e^{\frac12 (\gamma+\epsilon a) \mathbf i}
> =
> e^{\frac12 \epsilon \theta \mathbf n}
> e^{\frac12 \gamma \mathbf k}
> e^{\frac12 \beta  \mathbf j}
> e^{\frac12 \alpha \mathbf i}
> $$

What do you define $\mathbf{n}$ as? An arbitrary axis? I'm not sure that's right, but it could be; you'd have to look at first order BCH expansions.

There's a couple of standard ways for solving Euler angle problems on $SO(3)$. The first option is to create multiple sets of Euler angles and switch between the sets based on your current orientation. If you use this in feedback you need a bunch of logic around where the charts are patched together, so it gets messy. Otherwise you could transform the data to quaternions and set a fixed quaternion at the point where the Euler angles gimbal lock.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{n}$ is an arbitrary axis. I'm using [Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles) and start from some rotation described by the quaternion $e^{\frac12 \gamma \mathbf k}
e^{\frac12 \beta  \mathbf j}
e^{\frac12 \alpha \mathbf i}$. Then I make a small rotation $\epsilon\theta$ around some arbitrary axis $\mathbf{n}$ and want to know what are the new angles.

Comment: @md2perpe the general unit quaternion would be $e^{ai+bj+ck} \neq e^{ai}e^{bj}e^{ck}$ due to noncommutativity. Your formula would work if you had $q_eq = e^{\epsilon n} e^{ai+bj+ck}$ but not the way you have written it.

Comment: Have you read about the Tait-Bryan angles? First you rotate around one axis (here $x$), then around another ($y$), and finally around the third axis ($z$). As a quaternion that is represented as $e^{\frac12 \gamma \mathbf k} e^{\frac12 \beta  \mathbf j} e^{\frac12 \alpha \mathbf i}$. This will equal $e^{\frac12(\phi \mathbf{m})}$ for some angle $\phi$ and some axis $\mathbf{m}$ but as you write $\phi \mathbf{m} \neq \alpha \mathbf{i} + \beta \mathbf{j} + \gamma \mathbf{k}.$

Comment: @md2perpe I've never really seen Tait-Byran used so I am not very familiar. What you describe is the same process as Euler angles, just using a quaternion representation, so it's no surprise there is gimbal lock.